# WSO2 api manager asterisk in empty resource path

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have wso2 api manager version 2.1.0 where I have deployed API which has empty resource path for method get, up to here is all OK but when I want to call it from a store I see at the end asterisk which is preventing to get output and I am getting no content. when I call it with curl or postman without asterisk I get expected output.

in API manager 1.10 this was not presented.

Does anyone know how to get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue and will be fixed in a later release.

But you can try fixing it yourself. Have a look at `swagger-ui.js` and `swagger-ui.min.js` files in

```
wso2am-2.1.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/themes/wso2/templates/api/swagger/swagger
```

---

**Edit**: See this.

https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/pull/3325/files

Comment: hi, thanks for the input , however this isnt working for me I still see the star event I update swagger files and get no content response

Comment: Did you change min js file too? And tried after clearing cache too?

Comment: nope I changed only the ui.js nothing has changed with this one, but the min.js is problematic to me as I am not very familiar with javascript and I am not able to put it to proper position as it srews allways the api console page , any advice ?

Comment: what is really used is the min.js. so you can delete min.js and rename .js as min.js.

Comment: now it is correct at field request url, but it is still present in curl command in console, any other ideas? thank you

Comment: try to fix `// adds curl output` section in the js.

Comment: curlCommand = curlCommand.replace('*', ''); now it is not there , but still i get no response from server , I have to look deeper :)